# Webpack-dev-server Error: Cannot find module 'ipaddr.js'

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Running webpack dev server outputs the error below.

I tried running it through various using both local and global package.

I am using:

```
 "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
```

,

```
.\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server.cmd
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ipaddr.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DSL\Myriad\branches\HTML 5 GUI\V1.0_WebPack\node_modules\proxy-addr\index.js:24:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Comment: could you share your webpack configuration ?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the webpack config since it is not even reaching that stage. Just invoking webpack-dev-server --version should not throw the error

Comment: but webpack-dev-server is trying to find your webpack config file: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js

Comment: if you run "webpack-dev-server -v" or "webpack-dev-server -h" without a config file should run without any issues. try it out. it only shows the version or help. 

I even get the error there in such a simple step

Answer (score 3):

Just run this commands

`rm -rf node_modules
 npm i`

cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue but was not able to find an answer. The solution that I stumbled upon was to delete the **node modules** directory and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Type your project terminal 2 commands. I hope to solve this error

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score -2):

Got the same issue for some reason. Seems to be a missing "main" property in the package.json of the ipaddr.js module.

You can temporarily fix it by copying node_modules/ipaddr.js/lib/ipaddr.js to node_modules/ipaddr.js/index.js